# Multiple strings replacement in multiple files using Python

Tags: python, regex, yaml, substitution

I have a list of files and list of strings that needs to be replaced captured in an yaml file. I want to write a function that accepts this yaml file and performs the search and replace method. Here is what I have got so far

2 text files and yaml file

txt_1.txt

```
aB123.Abc
AB345.aBC
ab123.ABC
Ab345.abc
```

txt_2.txt

```
ab123.Abc
AB345.ABC
current_date
```

yaml_file - cf_master.yml

```
input_files:
    - txt_1.txt
    - txt_2.txt
replacement_strings:
    string1:
        from: AB123.ABC
        to: XY000.XYZ
    string2:
        from: AB345.ABC
        to:   XY001.ZYX
    string3:
        from: current_date
        to: '2018-04-07'
```

The intent is to replace all the strings (from values) to (to values) ignoring the case (case insensitive)

```
import yaml
import re

with open('cf_master.yml') as f:
        dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)

def string_replacer(dataMap):
    for files in dataMap['input_files']:
            with open(dataMap['input_files']) as f:
                input_h = f.read()
    for string in dataMap['replacement_strings']:
            output_h = input_h.replace(
                                      dataMap['replacement_strings'][string]['from'],
                                      dataMap['replacement_strings'][string]['to']
                                      )
    with open(output_dataMap[input_files],"w") as f:
                f.write(output_h)
    return output_dataMap[input_files]

string_replacer(dataMap)
```

I do not understand how to correct this code. The input files, yaml file and new files that are generated are all in the same folder

Comment: '_correct this code_" - you never told us what is wrong with your code in the first place.

Comment: Add the text of the error message that you're getting to your question

Answer (score 2):

You could probably simplify your `yaml` file.  The replacement strings don't need indexes

```
input_files:
    - txt_1.txt
    - txt_2.txt
replacement_strings:
    - from: AB123.ABC
      to: XY000.XYZ
    - from: AB345.ABC
      to:   XY001.ZYX
    - from: current_date
      to: '2018-04-07'
```

As far as replacing, you probably want to do the replacement in two passes, first replacing with a temp marker, and then going back and replacing the markers with the actual replacement.  This prevents replacements from interacting with each other. For example, where you replace all `'a'`'s with `'b'`'s and all `'b'`'s with `'c'`'s.  Without the intermediate marker step, the second replacement would replace all the original `'b'`'s, but also all the `'b'`'s from the replaced `'a'`'s.

```
import yaml
import re

with open('cf_master.yml') as f:
    data = yaml.safe_load(f)


for filepath in data['input_files']:
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        txt = f.read()

    marker_d = dict()
    for i, d in enumerate(data['replacement_strings']):
        marker = '__$TEMP{}$__'.format(i)
        marker_d[marker] = d['to']
        txt = re.sub(re.escape(d['from']), marker, txt, flags=re.I)

    for marker, s in marker_d.items():
        txt = re.sub(re.escape(marker), s, txt)

    # Save file somewhere?
```

Comment: Hi Brendan, Thanks for the 2-step technique. I'm going to remember this  as it helps to validate the outputs.  I added some trail code to route the output to a different file. the output file is basically the input file name prefixed with string 'output' and the order (Ex: output_1_input_1.txt) . The intent is to preserve the input for validation purposes. Can you help me solve how to route the outputs to a different file? Thanks Pari